# How to validate date in chrome browser as well as in firefox browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, cross-browser

In chrome I am trying to check date if it is valid date or not.

In have a variable:

```
var d = new Date('9/'); // Not a correct format
```

In Chrome

```
console.log(new Date('9/')); // Output: Sat Sep 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) Which is wrong as I am providing wrong date.
```

In Firefox

```
console.log(new Date('9/')); // Output: Invalid Date
```

Also using `date.toLocaleString()` has output `06 May 2007 00:00:00` in firefox

and in chrome it is `1/9/2001`;

So my question is how to validate date in chrome and keep code safe from these differences. If need more details about it please write in comment.

Comment: Use http://momentjs.com.

Comment: @MattBall this, or something similar, should be the answer. Stand on the shoulders of those who came before...and probably did it way better.

Comment: @MattBall I can't do this I need javascript solution. Page already have lot of frameworks.

Comment: A JavaScript library is still JavaScript. "Too many libraries" is a poor reason _not_ to introduce another one (for the right reasons). If you want something that behaves the same across browsers, when the different browsers don't, **use a library.**

Comment: Some regex solution? @MattBall

Comment: No. Don't reinvent the wheel. The minified library is under 7kb. Just use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Javascript Date API can have somewhat mixed results between browsers, as you've discovered.

The best option I can suggest is to use one of the third-party libraries that are available for this. There are two I can recommend  --  either [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/).

Both of these libs have much better validation and parsing, and are more consistent cross-browser than the built-in Date class.

Comment: Is it not possible from native javascript (without library)? I know these solutions but I need javascript only solution. Anyways thanks! @Spudley

Comment: Hey @Ashwin, I've used moment.js pretty heavily, and I can promise you it is pure Javascript. The project is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js), so you can check for yourself that [the only required file](https://rawgithub.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js) is just Javascript.

Comment: those libraries *are* javascript, so this is a javascript-only solution. The problem is that the Date class is inconsistent between browsers, so you need something else to do the parsing and validation. Your choices are either to write your own validation code or use an existing library. But even if you write your own, it's still a library; just one that you've written rather than someone else. Write your own if you want, but the ones I mentioned are there already, they're free, they've been properly tested, and they're well-known and work well. Your choice.

Comment: @Spudley You are right, I can't trust on Date API anymore. Using library is better than writing own. Although I had almost written a library to validate `Date` :) . +1 Accepted

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is to use a Javascript library as @Spudley suggested like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

However, if you don't want to include that awesome library (or another like it), you could try running your date through a regex like this:

```
var date = "9/",
    pattern = /(?:(?:\d{2}[-\/]){2}\d{4})|(?:\d{4}(?:[-\/]\d{2}){2})/,
    isValid = false;

isValid = pattern.test( date );
```

This will match `yyyy/mm/dd`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, `mm/dd/yyyy` and `yyyy/dd/mm` (plus a number of variations [and issues]).

### **However, this is extremely naive, doesn't match the vast majority of date formats, allows mixed separators, and a wide array of other issues.**

Again, I strongly recommend you implement a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), but this regex might be a start.